Tangent cone to a convex set is a convex cone
Let $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex set and let $\bar{y} \in Y$. The tangent cone to $Y$ at $\bar{y}$, denoted $T(Y, \bar{y})$, is the set of all limits of the form $h = \lim t_{l}(y_{l} - \bar{y})$, where $\{t_l\}$ is a sequence of non-negative reals and $\{y_{l}\}$ is a sequence in $Y$ with limit $\bar{y}$.
I'm trying to prove that $T(Y, \bar{y})$ is a convex cone. To this end, let $h$ and $h'$ be two points in $T(Y, \bar{y})$ and $\alpha, \beta$ be two positive reals. It seems clear that $\alpha h + \beta h'$ is the limit of a sequence $\{\alpha t_l(y_{l} - \bar{y}) + \beta t'_{l}(y'_{l} - \bar{y})\}$ for some $\{t_l\}$, $\{t'_l\}$ in $\mathbb{R_{+}}$ and $\{y_l\}$, $\{y'_l\}$ in $Y$ converging to $\bar{y}$. Can we construct a sequence $\{t''_l\}$ in $\mathbb{R_{+}}$ and a sequence $\{y''_l\}$ in $Y$ with limit $\bar{y}$ such that $\alpha t_l(y_{l} - \bar{y}) + \beta t'_{l}(y'_{l} - \bar{y}) = t''_l(y''_{l} - \bar{y})$ for all $l$? Or is there an easier way of showing that $\alpha h + \beta h' \in T(Y, \bar{y})$?

If $h\in T(Y,\overline{y})$, then for $t\in \mathbb R_+$ we have
$$ th = t\lim t_l(y_l - \overline y) = \lim (t t_l) (y_l - \overline y)\in T(Y, \overline{y}).$$
Furthermore, if $h, h' \in T(Y,\overline{y})$, then
$$ h +h' = \lim t_l(y_l - \overline y) + t_l' (y_l' - \overline y) = \lim (t_l + t_l') \Bigg( \underbrace{\frac{t_l}{t_l + t_l'} y_l  + \frac{t_l'}{t_l +t_l'}y_l'}_{\substack{\in Y\text{ by convexity and} \\ \text{converging to $\overline y$}}} - \overline y\Bigg) . $$

Shouldn't one give some sort of argument for why $t_l + t'_l > 0$ for sufficiently large $l$?

@AMfrn Well, if the $t_l + t_l'=0$, then we simply are simply the point $\overline y$ so we could just choose $t_l = t_l'=1$ and $y_l = y_l'= \overline y$ in that case. But the convex cone remains the same set whether we look at all sequences with $t_l\geq 0$ or all sequences with $t_l>0$.
